# Let $A$ be countable. Prove that the set of all finite sequences of elements of $A$ is countable.

Tags: functions, solution-verification, proof-writing

**Claim:** Let $A$ be countable. Then the set of all finite sequences of elements of $A$ is countable.
*Proof.*
A finite sequence of elements of $A$ is a function $f: I_{n} \rightarrow A$ where $I_n=\{1,2,...,n\}$. For each $n\in\mathbb{Z}^{+}$, let $^{I_n}A=\{f|f: I_{n} \to A\}$. The set of all finite sequences of elements of $A$ is $\bigcup_{n=1} (^{I_n}A)$. Given that a countable union of countable sets is countable, it is sufficient to prove that each $^{I_n}A$ is countable. To do this, we first prove $^{I_n}\mathbb{Z}^+$ is countable; then since $|A|\le|\mathbb{Z}^+$, $|^{I_n}A|\le |^{I_n}\mathbb{Z}^+|$. (1)

Define a function $f:^{I_n}\mathbb{Z}^{+}\rightarrow \mathbb{Z}^{+}$ as follows, take $h: I_{n} \rightarrow \mathbb{Z}^+$. Now define $f(h)=\prod_{i=1}^{n} p_{i}^{h(i)}$ where $p_{i}$ is the $i$th prime. To see that this is injective, let $h_{0}, h_{1}: I_{n} \rightarrow \mathbb{Z}^{+}$ with $h_0(j) \neq h_1(j)$ for some $j$. Then $v_{p_{j}}\left(h_{0}(j)\right) \neq v_{p_{j}}\left(h_{1}(j)\right)$, where $v_{p}(x)$ is the $\mathrm{p}$ adic valuation of $x$; clearly it follows that $\prod_{i=1}^{n}p_i^{h_0(i)}$ and $\prod_{i=1}^{n}p_i^{h_1(i)}$ have a different $p_j$ adic valuation, so they can't be equal; hence $f$ is injective. Injectivity from $^{I_n}\mathbb{Z}^+$ to $\mathbb{Z}^+$ implies $|^{I_n}\mathbb{Z}^+|\le|\mathbb{Z}^+|$, so we're done.

Is the proof valid? I also have a question about (1), in particular $|A|\le\|\mathbb{Z}^+|\implies|^{I_n}A|\le|^{I_n}\mathbb{Z}^+|$. I know that $|A|=|\mathbb{Z}^+|$ implies $|^{I_n}A|=|^{I_n}\mathbb{Z}^+|$ because I've proved it. But I haven't proved $|A|<|\mathbb{Z}^+|\implies|^{I_n}A|\le|\mathbb{Z}^+|$ .Now if $A$ is finite, i.e $|A|<|\mathbb{Z}^+|$, then it takes me 5 seconds to come to the conclusion that there being more functions from $I_n$ to $A$ than there are functions from $I_n$ to a countably infinite set, $\mathbb{Z}^+$, doesnt make sense; so I conclude that in this case $^{I_n}A$ is at most infinitely countable, there's no way it is uncountable. How "safe" is a conclusion like this? In math in general, is it ok to trust your intuition like this, or should you take the time to prove everything?

Comment: Your proof is ok. To prove (1), simply assume you have some injection $f:A\to\Bbb Z^+,$ and use it to construct an injection $A^n\to(\Bbb Z^+)^n.$